# Find the input/output probability distributions that realize the capacity of communications channel?

Tags: information-theory, mutual-information, communication

Consider two random variables $X,Y$. For simplicity, they are discrete and finite. Let $Q(y|x)$ be the conditional probability of $Y$ given $X$. Their mutual information is defined as:

$$I=H(Y)-H(Y|X)$$

where $H(Y)$ is the entropy of $Y$:

$$H(Y)=-\sum_y p_Y(y)\ln p_Y(y)$$

and $H(Y|X)$ is the conditional entropy of $Y$ given $X$, averaged over $X$:

$$H(Y|X)=-\sum_{x,y} p_X(x)Q(y|x)\ln Q(y|x)$$

The communications channel is defined by the distribution $Q(y|x)$, which determines the reliability of the channel. Given $Q(y|x)$, one would like to exploit as best as the information transfer capabilities of the channel. To do this, one has to chose a probability distribution $p_X(x)$ such that $I$, as defined above, is maximized (see [Shannon–Hartley theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem); this maximum value of $I$ is called the channel's *capacity*).

My question is, given $Q(y|x)$, can you give an explicit, or implicit form for $p_X(x)$? Or maybe $p_Y(y)$ (which is determined by $p_X(x)$ as $p_Y(y) = \sum_x p_X(x) Q(y|x))$?

Answer (score 1):

There is no general analytic solution to the maximization problem for finding channel capacity, but there is a well known numeric algorithm, called the [Blahut–Arimoto algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blahut%E2%80%93Arimoto_algorithm).

For a given $Q(y|x)$, the algorithm iteratively computes

$$C = \max_{p} I(p, Q)$$

and produces as output both $p(x)$ and $C$. For a detailed description of the algorithm and proof of its behaviors, see:

- Blahut, Richard. "Computation of channel capacity and rate-distortion functions." IEEE transactions on Information Theory 18.4 (1972): 460-473.